# Connecting to local server in SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssms, sql-server-config-manager

I have tried EVERY suggestion I have found so far in SE and nothing works. Let me explain what  is going on.

I am a PHP developer and I am making a transition to ASP. So I am developing a website locally and I need a database going, also locally. But like I said, I can't add the NORTHWND database because I don't have the server up and running. I read through the tutorials and I seen to be missing a piece of every puzzle.

I have SQL Server 2008 running.

- These guys [Add Database](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20987/HowTo-Install-the-Northwind-and-Pubs-Sample-Databa) say to attach the database via VS12. I have no such option to "Attach"
- These guys here [Connect to your server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/0wbea1ae%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) say to connect to the SQL server but I can't connect. When I try, I get an error that says:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named
>   Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)
>   (.Net SqlClient Data Provider)

I also noticed there was a localdb with username LOTUSMS. I don't remember ever making a username for anything here. And I can't remove it or make one up. (Windows Authentication)

- And then these guys [Turn on your Server Service](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/05/21/sql-server-fix-error-provider-named-pipes-provider-error-40-could-not-open-a-connection-to-sql-server-microsoft-sql-server-error/) say the Server must be up and running and to log into the SQL server Configuration Manager and ensure the SQL services are running. Well, they are not. It says "the remote procedure call failed" and there is no other options to restart or edit or anything

So as you can see, I know my problems, but I can't find the solution to them. Anyone? I am not sure as to what logs or extra evidence you may need, so before I go adding unnecessary text and pics here, I'll leave it open and produce the evidence as requested.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you know if you have administrative rights on your machine?

Comment: I do. I decided to just get a server and go that route. This took too long. But thanks anyway